# how can I remove this 'breadcrumb' without getting syntax?

Tags: php, html

I just need this to be invisible, but I keep getting errors. Any ideas?

I have tried to cut out different parts of it, but for now I don't need it on my webpage. So how do I make it visibly disappear?

```
<div id="breadcrumbs">
<?php if(function_exists('bcn_display')) { bcn_display(); } 
      else { ?>
<a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Forside','Chameleon') ?></a> <span class="raquo">&raquo;</span>

<?php if( is_tag() ) { ?>
    <?php esc_html_e('Posts Tagged ','Chameleon') ?><span class="raquo">&quot;</span><?php single_tag_title(); echo('&quot;'); ?>
<?php } elseif (is_day()) { ?>
    <?php esc_html_e('Posts made in','Chameleon') ?> <?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?>
<?php } elseif (is_month()) { ?>
    <?php esc_html_e('Posts made in','Chameleon') ?> <?php the_time('F, Y'); ?>
<?php } elseif (is_year()) { ?>
    <?php esc_html_e('Posts made in','Chameleon') ?> <?php the_time('Y'); ?>
<?php } elseif (is_search()) { ?>
    <?php esc_html_e('Search results for','Chameleon') ?> <?php the_search_query() ?>
<?php } elseif (is_single()) { ?>
    <?php $category = get_the_category();
      $catlink = get_category_link( $category[0]->cat_ID );
      echo ('<a href="'.esc_url($catlink).'">'.esc_html($category[0]-
```

Comment: General tip: If you get an error message, TELL US what it was. As for "deleting parts"... what parts? Would you be happy if you went to a surgeon and they just randomly stabbed at you until you were "cured"?

Comment: Your code is broken at the end.

Comment: okay i need to make this not visibel on my page

Comment: <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Forside','Chameleon') ?></a> <span class="raquo">&raquo;</span>

*forside* and *Chameleon*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to wrap the breadcrumbs in `<!-- (code here) -->`

This is not the BEST way - not by any means - but if you just want it not to be visible right now, this will do the trick. What you're basically doing is telling the browser "this is not code, this is a comment; do not display this."

So your code would look like this:

```
<div id="breadcrumbs"><!--
(your current breadcrumb code - remains unchanged from how it is now)
--></div>
```

Or, if you don't even want the space the div takes up to be on the page, like this:

```
<!--<div id="breadcrumbs">
(your current breadcrumb code - remains unchanged from how it is now)
</div>-->
```